# Are there any virtualization systems that have good support for dual monitors?

Tags: windows, linux, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine

Are there any good virtualization programs that work well with dual monitors?  I'm using VirtualBox, and there doesn't seem to be any way to get it to use both of my monitors.  If it matters, I'm using a Windows host with a Linux (Debian) guest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) on MacOSX supports up to 4 physical monitors virtually. I am not sure about Windows however. [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/ws/) supports multiple desktop spanning so I would assume it would be able to support it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, but VMWare workstation is way too expensive for me.  :-(

Comment: @Jason. Understandable. Unfortunately it is the only one that spends time on doing proper multiple desktop support.

Comment: I'm using VMWare Player with an XP VM and Windows 7 VM and both support dual monitors. Had to manually edit the vm-hardware setting in the vmx file to get windows 7 to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual Box Now works with multiple Monitors.  I recently tested a multimonitor Ubuntu VM within a windows 7 Host, worked Great!  I cannot find the notes in the original changelog, but I am running VirtualBox 4.0.10.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, just tried it out and it worked fine.